# Who first defined locally convex topological vector spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview, locally-convex-spaces

Who first defined the class of locally convex topological vector spaces?

Comment: According to the historical notes of Bourbaki's *Topological Vector Spaces*, "a general definition of locally convex spaces was given by Kolmogoroff and J. von Neumann in 1935". They do not give more precise references.

Comment: M. Frechet...?!

Comment: I was also thinking of Frechet, although I guess he is mainly credited for the idea of abstract metric space and basically the birth of modern functional analysis.

Comment: Frechet introduced metric vector spaces. "Topology" was not introduced yet when Frechet worked on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Attributed to von Neumann (1935) in Dieudonné ([1953, p. 496](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=62334); [1981, p. 218](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=605488)), Köthe ([1956](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=80262), [p. 20](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002134764)), Schaefer ([1971, p. 37](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=342978)), Pietsch ([2007](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2300779), [p. 68](https://books.google.com/books?id=MMorKHumdZAC&pg=PA68)), Narici-Beckenstein ([2011, p. 82](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2723563)):

> The first to consider LCS was von Neumann [[1935](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?61.0632.04), p. 4] who called them
>   convex spaces; the term “locally convex space” was first used by Tihonov
>   [[1935](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?61.1195.01), p. 768].

(To Kolmogorov ([1934](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?60.1229.02)) they attribute general topological vector spaces. Wehausen ([1938, p. 158](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?64.0367.01)) has a detailed comparison of the axioms in Kolmogorov, von Neumann, and Tikhonov.)

Answer (score 6):

The reference to Kolmogorov is Studia Math, 5 (1934), 29-33. In my opinion, the most reliable source of references to classical papers is the book by Dunford-Schwartz, Linear Operators. They mention also the paper of von Neumann.

Kolmogorov writes about convexity in his note.